# Which component is missing from this Firebase setup? [basic]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time interacting with Google Firebase and I am a JS beginner. I need to simply put the Firebase JSON into a variable called `rss`. After running the code below with appropriate connections I have not been able to output anything.

Is there a missing component?

Is the table being called correctly?

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "abc",
    authDomain: "<authdomainPlaceHolder>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<URLplaceHolder>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "gs://<PlaceHolder>.appspot.com",
    //messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>", // NOT USED
  };

 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 var database = firebase.database();

 var ref = database.ref("results");
 ref.once("collection1", function(snapshot) {
    var rss = snapshot.val();
 });

 document.write(rss);
</script>
```

[image: database preview]

Answer (score 0):

The call to firebase doesn't happen right away, so you're variable is empty. Move your code to look like this:

```
ref.once("collection1", function (snapshot) {
    var rss = snapshot.val();
    document.write(rss);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mathew. After applying the code it is still empty. Could the issue be the way I'm calling the JSON content?

Comment: Maybe, try a console log instead of a document.write and look at the developer tools console.